# Could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments, add multiple elements to array

Tags: swift

I've got following variable defined:

```
var mapHorizontalConstraints:Array = Array<NSLayoutConstraint>()
```

later when I'm trying to set the value of my constraints array using Visual Format Language as follow:

```
    mapHorizontalConstraints =  NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-0-[mapView]-0-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0),
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["mapView":mapView])
```

I'm getting "Could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments", with a little arrow pointing to `"="` sign in above assignment.

I believe it's because we cannot add to array using `"="`. If I could add multiple elements using array's `append()` function I would have tried that, but as you know `append()` just accepts one single element.

So just wondering if this is my issue, and if so, how can I add multiple elements to array in Swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set a variable to type `Array`, you need to explicitly write out the type, like this:

`var mapHorizontalConstraints:Array<NSLayoutConstraint> = ...`

or more simply,

`var mapHorizontalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = ...`

As mentioned in the comments, `NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat` returns `[AnyObject]!`

Thus when you assign it, you should downcast like this:

```
 mapHorizontalConstraints =  NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-0-[mapView]-0-|",
        options: 0,
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["mapView":mapView]) as [NSLayoutConstraint]
```

You can append to it with the `+=` operator.

Comment: I noticed that `NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat` returns `AnyObject[]`. Does Swift require a cast to `Array<NSLayoutConstraint>`?

Comment: @Palpatim check edit :], this is definitely the recommended way

Comment: @Palpatim And also you can append this way by calling `+=` on any object of type `NSLayoutConstraint` or `NSLayoutConstraint []`

Comment: Just a little change to this and I'll mark it as the answer, as @Palpatim said, NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat returns AnyObject[]!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    var mapHorizontalConstraints:AnyObject[] = []
```

to set use the '=' operator, to add to the array '+=' as in

```
mapHorizontalConstraints += [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *can* add multiple elements to an array with the += operator, e.g.

```
array += [4,5,6]
```

(example taken from the Swift Standard Library Reference.

But there's a different issue: the NSArray * that you get back comes through in swift as an `AnyObject[]`, which you then need to downcast in order to use. See the Section on Cocoa data types in the Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C document from Apple.